# NodeJS HTTP - listen on other port than 80

Tags: node.js, apache, http, xampp

I am running XAMPP on Windows to host an Apache server on port 80. Now I'm trying to have a NodeJS script running in the background but the problem is that it can only listen on port 80. If it does, everything works as it should but I can't have Apache running at the same time, because Apache takes priority and just serves my website. The NodeJS script doesn't even get to listen.

My question is: how do I switch the listening port of the NodeJS script (the specific port really doesn't matter) so that Apache can still run on port 80 and I can reach the NodeJS script from all around the world.

Part of the NodeJS code:

```js
const http = require('http');

const port = 8080;
const host = '0.0.0.0';




server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
            doStuff(body);
        });
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text'});
        res.end('received request successfully');
    }
    else {
        res.writeHead(405, {'Content-Type': 'text'});
        res.end('not allowed method ' + req.method + ', try again with GET or POST');
    }

})

server.listen(port, null, function(error){
  if(!!error){
    console.log("\x1b[41m%s\x1b[0m", "error while initializing listener on port " + port + ": " + error);
   }
   else{
    console.log("\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m", "started listener at 'http://" + host + ':' + port + "'");}
 });
```

[Additional information is in my other question which got flagged as duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426031/nodejs-use-other-port-than-80-for-public-access?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: You need to set reverse proxy for that. Google that out

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal thanks, I'll look it up

Comment: What's the error you get when you change the port?

Comment: @willascend sorry for the late reply. I get no error. It starts normally. It just can't get any data.

Comment: Got it. That indicates that the server is likely running on the port as specified. It does sound like the issue is accessing the node servers without using the port in the url. Please try the reverse proxy to get this to work. It may also help to provide additional information on how you are setting up your apache server and how you expect to access the node servers externally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53426031/nodejs-use-other-port-than-80-for-public-access?noredirect=1&lq=1), which was marked as duplicate of this one, you've got some additional information there that will probably help to elucidate what you're needing. Specifically, you mention the following:

> I want to host multiple http servers with NodeJS, that all get and send http requests. At the same time I want to have Apache running, which occupies port 80. If I disable Apache and let NodeJS run on port 80, it will work but I can't have them running at the same time.
>
> This script will run and receive requests locally at port 8081, but I can't seem to send an AJAX request to it through the Internet, even after forwarding the port with my router:

I think @ankit-agarwal is probably right in that you need a reverse proxy setup to forward traffic to your different backends. Assuming you've got an externally facing IP address, you should be able to access each of your backends using the ports they are listening on. For example, if the exposed public IP address of your machine is 100.120.110.43:

```
+---------+------+-------------------------------------+
| Backend | Port |             Web Address             |
+=========+======+=====================================+
| Apache  |   80 | 100.120.110.43 or 100.120.110.43:80 |
| Node1   | 8080 | 100.120.110.43:8080                 |
| Node2   | 8081 | 100.120.110.43:8081                 |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------+
```

If you want to access each of the backends without specifying the port, you have to have some way to tell your internal network which backend to serve based on the request. One way of doing this is to use path based routing, where you setup your reverse proxy to route the traffic to the different backends based on the path in the url. You didn't post your Apache configuration, but you can use your current Apache server to handle this using the [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) and [ProxyPassReverse](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) directives similar to below:

```
ProxyPass "/node1"  "http://100.120.110.43:8080/"
ProxyPassReverse "/node1"  "http://100.120.110.43:8080/"

ProxyPass "/node2"  "http://100.120.110.43:8081/"
ProxyPassReverse "/node2"  "http://100.120.110.43:8081/"
```

The cool thing about using a reverse proxy is that you don't have to expose your node backends to the public. Let's assume you haven't, and they are only accessible from the internal network at 0.0.0.0:port.

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/apache
    ServerName www.apachefrontend.com
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass /node1  http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /node1  http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPass /node2  http://0.0.0.0:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse /node2  http://0.0.0.0:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

You could also point to different hosts/ips that only you have access to.

Finally, you can also use VirtualHost and ServerName if you have different DNS records to point to the different backends.

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/apache
    ServerName www.apachefrontend.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.nodebackend1.com
    ProxyRequests off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location />
        ProxyPass /  http://0.0.0.0:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse /  http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.nodebackend2.com
    ProxyRequests off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Location />
        ProxyPass /  http://0.0.0.0:8081/
        ProxyPassReverse /  http://0.0.0.0:8081/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

For any of the above to work, you need to have `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` enabled in apache.

These probably aren't the most robust examples and I haven't tested them, but they should demonstrate the idea. You can learn more [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am currently at work and can't test it out, but I'll make sure to try it out later today.

Comment: I tried to do exactly what you said and copied the first bit of code to the httpd.conf (I removed the Listen 80 because I already have it). Also I uncommented both mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http. But restarting the server resulted in Apache not wanting to start up.
This is my httpd.conf: https://pastebin.com/NHDzsLeV

Comment: It was not starting up because I didn't put the DocumentRoot in quotes. Now it gives me a 404 Error on POST request which wouldn't be a huge problem but now still Apache takes the request and doesn't redirect it to 0.0.0.0:8081

Comment: After a bit of experimentation, I finally got it to work with the first code snippet you provided. The problem was that I misconfigured my request and that I had a stray, second `ServerName` in my httpd.conf.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just change your node.js server port something like:

```
var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Ready on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

where 8080 is node.js server' new port.

Comment: That doesn't work, even if I open that port on my router

Comment: Can you show me how you set up your node.js server? Embed your code to your question

Comment: I added the snippet. I can't post everything as it is used for my work though.

Comment: change port to 8000

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really understood what you meant by you're not getting any response, because I ran the same code and it works fine for me.

I only noticed something here (I kept a note for you in the comment)

```
server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
            doStuff(body); //you haven't defined doStuff so you will end up with a error message on this line, but you sever will still run fine
        });
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text'});
        res.end('received request successfully'); 
    }
    else {
        res.writeHead(405, {'Content-Type': 'text'});
        res.end('not allowed method ' + req.method + ', try again with GET or POST');
    }

})
```

[image: Postman image]

When running your post request, don't forget to add `""` in your **body** area, select **raw** then choose **JSON(application/json)**. That should run fine for you, except you might get a `reference error` as shown below, but you should still get your response of `received request successfully`.

**error**

```
            doStuff(body);
            ^

ReferenceError: doStuff is not defined
```

Ensure that you're doing the same thing and let us know if your issue it resolved.

Comment: `doStuff(body);` was just a placeholder. In reality I have another function. I never get any request on the server, it doesn't show any kind of activity.

Comment: Also, as a one year late followup: localhost was never the problem. I wanted it to be accessible through the internet

Comment: Oh great! So I'm assuming that everything was working fine for you then.

Comment: It wasn't working fine at the time of making the issue but then I could fix it with a reverse proxy

Comment: Okay, so does that then mean that you still have the same issue up till now?

Comment: Nah, I followed `willascend`'s instructions (the accepted answer) and got it to work within a few hours

Answer (score 0):

Seem something already running on your `8080` port. Simply change to another port. For example `7000`
And make sure that all request you call to nodejs app like this

```
localhost:7000 // Normal we run at port 80 url simply localhost without port
```

Comment: Nothing is running on that port. I have already checked with netstat. Also I tried 8081.

Answer (score 0):

This is same scenario as using NodeJs in a Shared Hosting. I have written a blogpost about it [here](https://medium.com/trappedpanda/node-application-deployment-in-shared-hosting-like-godaddy-5b1408c23ea7)

Let me give an excerpt.

> 1. Just run the NodeJS server at let's say `8080` port.
> 2. Now, let's say your Apache serves at http://example.com, create a folder in your `public_html` or `www`. let's say the name is `server`. So, your new folder path is http://example.com/server
> 3. create a `.htaccess` file in the server folder
> 4. add the following lines,
>
>    ```
>    RewriteEngine On
>    RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/ [P,L] #which is your node server ip:port
>    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L] #same ip:port
>    ```

This will redirect all the requests from `http://example.com/server` to your Node server.

Comment: This gives me a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: can you check if request actually coming to the nodejs server or not? because i have same settings working for me just fine.

Comment: No, it isn't. I just get a 500 Error.

Comment: did you add the comments as well? like `#which is..` and `#same ip` . please remove that and try. Just tested it in my local setup

Comment: That doesn't change a thing sadly.

Comment: don't know man, have a local apache and made the exactly same thing. using the .htaccess and your nodejs code. and it works fine. getting `received request successfully`

Answer (score 0):

If I want use Apache and Nodejs in same port:
**npm http-proxy-middleware**

**1. Set Apache Port = 81**

[apache dir]/conf/httpd.conf

> ~59: Listen 81

**2. Set nodejs APP port = 3050**

> server.listen(3050);
>   // on linux ports<1000 require root privilegue

**3. Use third proxy APP (http-proxy-middleware)**

```
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware
  var express = require('express');
  var proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

  // proxy middleware options
  var options = {
      target: 'http://localhost:81', // target host ROOT
      changeOrigin: true, // needed for virtual hosted sites
      ws: true, // proxy websockets
      pathRewrite: {
          // '^/api/old-path' : '/api/new-path',     // rewrite path
          // '^/api/remove/path' : '/path'           // remove base path        
      },
      router: {
          // Examples:
          // when request.headers.host == 'dev.localhost:3000',
          // override target 'http://www.example.org' to 'http://localhost:8000'
          // 'dev.localhost:3000' : 'http://localhost:8000',
          // 'localhost:9000': 'localhost:9002/sub',                 
          // '/sub': 'http://localhost:9002',

          'localhost': 'http://localhost:81',         //Root to Apache
          'sub.localhost': 'http://localhost:3050',  // internal
          'sub.mydomain.com': 'http://localhost:3050', //external
      },
  };

  // create the proxy (without context)
  // var proxy_wp = proxy(options_wp);
  var proxy_node = proxy(options);

  // mount `exampleProxy` in web server
  var app = express();
  app.use(proxy_node);
  app.listen(80);
```

Then:

1. localhost:80 - is apache site
2. sub.localhost:80 - node
3. localhost:80/sub - node, if you set

for task runner i use **npm PM2**