# NodeJS - use other port than 80 for public access

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, portforwarding

[I have asked this question before, but I still haven't got an answer so I'm asking again.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52926017/8602926)

I want to host multiple http servers with NodeJS, that all get and send http requests. At the same time I want to have Apache running, which occupies port 80. If I disable Apache and let NodeJS run on port 80, it will work but I can't have them running at the same time.

This script will run and receive requests locally at port 8081, but I can't seem to send an AJAX request to it through the Internet, even after forwarding the port with my router:

```js
const http = require('http');

const port = 8081;
const host = '0.0.0.0';




server = http.createServer( function(req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
            doStuff(body);
        });
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text'});
        res.end('received request successfully');
    }
    else {
        res.writeHead(405, {'Content-Type': 'text'});
        res.end('not allowed method ' + req.method + ', try again with GET or POST');
        console.log("        \x1b[41mgot unexpected request '" + req.method + "' by '" + ipaddr + "' - aborting with status 405\x1b[0m\n");
    }

});


server.listen(port, null, function(error){
  if(!!error){
    console.log("\x1b[41m%s\x1b[0m", "error while initializing listener on port " + port + ": " + error);
   }
   else{
    console.log("\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m", "started listener at 'http://" + host + ':' + port + "'");}
 });
```

Comment: Use [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to attract attention to questions where you haven't found an answer, not duplicates.

Comment: If your question has not get the right answer you might consider giving bounty that will give more attention and motivation for more potential answers

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Sorry